# Changing parent on Drawer component results in window not responding

Tags: qt, qml

I want the Drawer to be relative to the Item, such that the Rectangle is never hidden.

When I change the parent of the Drawer component to the Item, the Drawer stops working and the window stops responding after 5-10 sec.

If I don't make any changes to the parent, it works fine. Except the Rectangle gets hidden when the Drawer is swiped out.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
Window{
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 800

    Row{
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        Rectangle{
            width: 80
            height: parent.height
            z: 2
        }

        Item{
            id: mainView
            height: parent.height
            width: parent.width - 80

            Drawer{
                parent: mainView // <-- causes not responding
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                edge: Qt.LeftEdge
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is using a `Drawer` when you don't want to have, what that `Drawer` is.

There are two solutions:

1. You write your own `Drawer` that is, what you want a `Drawer` to be.
2. You layer 2 `Window`s and have the drawer in the second window.

*// example:*

```
Window{
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 800

    Row{
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        Rectangle{
            width: 80
            height: parent.height
            z: 2
            color: 'green'
        }

        Window {
            id: mainView
            y: window.y
            x: window.x + 80
            height: 800
            width: 1200
            visible: true

            flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint

            color: 'red'

            Drawer{
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                edge: Qt.LeftEdge

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that like this you can't click through the second window, so you need to put in the good stuff in that window.

Comment: Thank you, I made my own component